# Using gdal_calc multiple times within a Python Script, Issues with Visual C++ for Python 2.7

Tags: c++, python-2.7, gdal, osgeo

I've exhausted what I'm capable of currently regarding the script that I have posted below. I am unable to properly call gdal_calc.py with this script. I have received various error message regarding a lack of .dll files to a win32 error.

I have installed and reinstalled GDAL, however I continue to receive an error message that suggests I don't have osgeo, and I cannot install GDAL properly within my Python27 pathway because of an issue with Visual C++ for Python because I either don't have the proper .bat file OR I get this message.

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory

I would appreciate even a direction to be point in, because I am a novice and this is over my head.

Thanks,

```
import os
import sys
from osgeo import gdal
from gdalconst import *
import numpy as np
import math
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import math
import PIL
from PIL import Image

# constants

gdalTranslate = r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_translate.exe'
src = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\RUA_FIL\IMG-HV-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img"
srcVH = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\RUA_FIL\IMG-VH-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img"
dstVH = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\vhFloat32-3.img"
dst = r"C:\\Users\jack\Desktop\\New_Trash\hvFloat32-3.img"
cmd = "-ot Float32 -of HFA" # hopefully this works
#gdalCalc = r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts\dist\gdal_calc.exe'
#hvFloat32 = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\hvFloat32-1.img"
#vhFloat32 = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\hvFloat32-1.img"


#prevName = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\RUA_FIL\IMG-HV-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA"
#newName = r"C:\Users\jack\Desktop\RUA_FIL\IMG-HV-ALOS2110871010-160611-HBQR1.5RUA.img"

#os.rename(prevName,newName)


# setting def

#def gdal_Translate (item):
    #return item
hvfullCmd = ' '.join([gdalTranslate, cmd, gdal_Translate(src), gdal_Translate(dst)])
subprocess.Popen(hvfullCmd)

vhfullCmd = ' '.join([gdalTranslate,cmd,gdal_Translate(srcVH),gdal_Translate(dstVH)])
subprocess.Popen(vhfullCmd)


# Run gdal_calc.py for HV

try:
    os.system('C:\Users\jack\Python\QGIS Python Scripts\ridofZs.py')
except:
    print ("This isn't working")
    sys.exit()


subprocess.call([sys.executable,'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\hvFloat32.img', '--outfile=C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\NEWCALCHV-2.img','--calc=A*(A>=1)'])



# Run gdal_calc.py for VH

#subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\vhFloat32.img', '--outfile=C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\NEWCALCVH-2.img','--calc=A*(A>=1)'])


# Run gdal_calc.py to dB for HV

#subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\NEWCALCHV-2.img', '--outfile=C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\HVindB.img','--calc=10*log10(power(A,2))-83'])


# Run gdal_calc.py to dB for HV

#subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\NEWCALCVH-2.img', '--outfile=C:\Users\jack\Desktop\New_Trash\VHindB.img','--calc=10*log10(power(A,2))-83'])


# Open Rasters using GDAL

hvRaster = gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\jack\\Desktop\\New_Trash\\hvFloat32.img")
vhRaster = gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\jack\\Desktop\\New_Trash\\vhFloat32.img")


# Get RasterBand

hvRasterBand = hvRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
vhRasterBand = vhRaster.GetRasterBand(1)


# Get Raster Mean

hvMean = hvRasterBand.GetStatistics(0,1)[2]
vhMean = vhRasterBand.GetStatistics(0,1)[2]


#### Maybe not needed
print hvMean
print vhMean

# calculate stDev

rasterList = (hvMean,vhMean)
stDev = np.std(rasterList)

#print stDev

if stDev >= 0.06:
    print "The imagery isn't acceptable"


if stDev <= 0.06:
    print "The imagery is acceptable"
```

Comment: How did you install GDAL library and gdal python module ? Maybe you can try to install it from pre-built wheels for windows from [C. Gohlke website](www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Also if you are doing GIS in windows maybe you heard about [osgeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) ? It will allow you to install (amongst other) GDAL library, a python distribution, QGIS, etc. (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165104/53915 for some details)

Comment: The first time that I installed GDAL, I used the .msi files provided at gisinternals (http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php). However, once I downloaded the necessary files I still ran into the same issue. "Cannot find   module osgeo". I've also tried osgeo4w, however it doesn't seem like I can pass commands through it. I tried using the subprocess.call to use gdal_calc within it, but I was unsuccessful.